# Android support action bar not showing overflow menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overflow, android-support-library

My android app supports 2.2 and higher. I'm using the appcompat support library for the action bar, so it should only show if there are things that don't fit. I want my action bar to support the overflow button (the three vertical squares) that reveals a menu with the other items when clicked.

In my menu file, I have three items set up. However on the app I only see two of them, and the overflow button is not showing as well.

activity_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:sord.ids_connect="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/checkbox"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        sord.ids_connect:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings2"
        android:icon="@drawable/checkbox_checked"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        sord.ids_connect:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings3"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        sord.ids_connect:showAsAction="ifRoom" />  

</menu>
```

java file

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class Activity_Menu extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_menu, menu);
        //return true;
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                super.onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

manifest

```
    <activity
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
        android:name="sord.ids_connect.Activity_Menu"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_menu" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: Did you press the MENU button on your device or emulator? On the emulator, the MENU button is mapped to PgUp.

Comment: Im testing on my phone, and when I press the menu button, I see the menu appear on the bottom with only 1 option that says "Settings", also why is only 1 option appearing there when I have 3 items in the menu file?

Answer (score 15):

General reference

1 - Override onCreateOption and inflate the menu

**Note**

Doesn't matter if you return true or call super

```
@Override

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

2 - Add the namespace to the menu.xml file.

```
xmlns:**yourapp**="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

3 - set the showAsAction to **always** or **ifRoom**

```
**yourapp**:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

4 - if you are using appcompat make sure that you Activity extends **ActionBarActivity** , you don't have to change any value of the ActionBar to be able to see you menuOption in the bar.

Finally you will have something like [remember to user a proper namespace for **yourapp**]

> main.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

on your Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"

This hack made it work - showing menu items even if Physical buttons are available.

Comment: how to do this in java without xml?

Comment: Okay, I found it in SupportMenuItem.setShowAsAction()

Comment: Hi @eOnOe .. I followed your instructions EXACTLY but I just cannot make the overflow appear .. weird .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720815

Answer (score 8):

If you are using the support library you'll need to declare the showAsAction from your own namespace; which will look like this `app:showAsAction`. You can refer to [eOnOe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21031834/2247689)'s answer for this.

**Using `android:showAsAction` won't work with the support library because it uses it's own implementation of the action bar rather than the framework's implementation of it.**

You can also always group items into the icon for example:

```
<item ... 
      android:icon="@drawable/abs__ic_menu_moreoverflow_holo_dark">
  <menu>    
   <item .../>
   <item .../>
  </menu>
</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

Android show overflow menu only if your device doesn't have menu button. Of course you can create hack a do it default for everyone device but it is't recommended solution. And for your every items add `android:showAsAction="never"` and this say your device show overflow menu if you don't have menu button.

Answer (score 1):

> Im testing on my phone, and when I press the menu button, I see the menu appear on the bottom with only 1 option that says "Settings"

That is the overflow.

> also why is only 1 options appearing there when I have 3 items in the menu file?

Because the other two are in the action bar. You specified `ifRoom`, and there were room for two, not three.

Comment: Oh i see, but How can I make the three dot button appear on top?

Comment: @omega: It will appear at the top on devices that lack a MENU button, and on any devices running Android 4.4 and higher. See my blog post for more: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/12/09/menu-key-dead-again.html

Comment: @omega: You can try `openOptionsMenu()` on `Activity`, though this should not be needed.

Comment: @omega: "What do you mean on "Activity"" -- `Activity` is a class. `openOptionsMenu()` is a method on the `Activity` class. You can call `openOptionsMenu()` on your `Activity` and see if that opens the overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to menu the menu layout as below

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:sord.ids_connect="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_container"
    android:title="Menu"
    android:showAsAction="never">        
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/checkbox"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    sord.ids_connect:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings2"
    android:icon="@drawable/checkbox_checked"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    sord.ids_connect:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings3"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    sord.ids_connect:showAsAction="ifRoom" />  
</item>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     Change Your menu.xml with the following code.




    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:sord.ids_connect="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_container"
        android:title="Menu"
       android:showAsAction="always">        
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/checkbox"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings2"
        android:icon="@drawable/checkbox_checked"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings3"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="always" />  
    </item>

    </menu>
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. I solved it by:

1) commenting `return true;`

2) uncommenting `return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);`

in public `boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`