# ActionBar not appearing in any activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to add AcionBar to my application.
I created a BaseActivity where all other activities extend it:

BaseActivity.java

```
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class Main extends BaseActivity {
// other code..
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/BaseTheme" >



        <activity
            android:name="omar.asd.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

themes.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="BaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        <!-- hide the Window Title -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>

        <!-- You could change the scrollbar, checkbox style, anything! -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

As you can see, I created a custom theme, BaseTheme, to apply "Theme.AppCompat.Light" to all the application..
The problem is that the ActionBar doesnt appear in any activity..

Why is this?

Comment: it may be same however i am not sure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20713806/android-support-action-bar-not-showing-overflow-menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- hide the Window Title -->
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Your App theme is no titile,so ActionBar impossible appear in any activity

Answer (score 0):

Add a style for your ActionBar in the styles.xml

`<style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
        <item name="android:background">#1998ca</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">15dip</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>`

and then add these two items in your BaseTheme

`<item name="android:windowTitleSize">40dip</item>
 <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>`

and remove this item from your BaseTheme
`<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>`